# How to perform a FULL OUTER JOIN in TALEND tool?

Tags: etl, talend

I am using TALEND Bigdata studio for ETL.

I have a case where I need to do a full outer join between two datasets but in talend studio I could not find a full outer join option.

How do i do it ?

Comment: you can check the [link](http://donotforgetitmaster.blogspot.in/2016/11/full-join-in-talend-introduction-there.html).

Answer (score -1):

Edit:

in the tMap, when you map two columns from two tables,you have two tables. The parent main flow table (first one in the stack of tables on the left), and a child table, that is referencing the parent table.

The trick is very simple. You know when you drag'n'drop an attribute from a parent to a child table you will get a connection and in the child attribute you will have the name of the parent table's attribute to be matched upon. 
The trick here is to have in the child table a mapping relation not to the parent but to anything else (like a context variable) that will always produce true.

I would usually have in the child flow  an additional bool attribute added (not coming from the source) and by default set to true, and in the child mapping in tMap I would have it "joined" to true.

The result is that all record join attempts are interpreted as successfull join and you will get a Cartesian product join result

Comment: The options to match rows do not mean full outer join. It is still looking for matches while the question is asking for a Full Outer Join

Comment: yes you are right. I forgot completely. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll edit it now.